# Cinnamon desktop background brightness being changed

Tags: 16.04, cinnamon

Running Ubuntu 16.04 and just switched over to the Cinnamon desktop.  I set a background image from Firefox by right-clicking on an image.  When I boot to the login screen the image is displayed correctly.  After entering my password the desktop is shown and for just a second the image look fine.  Then it looks like some kind of special effect is being applied... you can watch the image brightness being raised over a span of about a half second.  The highlights in the image are completely blown out.

Below are two crops.  The first shows part of the original image... this is how it appears briefly after logging on.  The second shows the brightened version.  I've looked through various settings and disable various effects but nothing seems to be working.  Just to clarify, the unaltered image does briefly appear and the image on the disk is correct... this is clearly being applied to it on the fly.

[image: Original image]

[image: Background as shown in Cinnamon]

Comment: I was looking for the same thing, can't believe nobody figured this out in the past year. I'll get back here if I find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution from this bug report on Github: [Desktop background not displaying correctly](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/6161#issuecomment-271660084)

> Make sure to upgrade all muffin packages to their latest version
>   (3.2.2 at the moment).
>
> And then, open a terminal and type:
>
> ```
> gsettings set org.cinnamon.muffin background-transition fade-in
> ```
>
> That should solve the color issue.

If you don't like the fade-in effect, you can also use:

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.muffin background-transition none
```

To list all possible values, run:

```
gsettings range org.cinnamon.muffin background-transition
```

The offending value (and, on my machine, the only other one) seems to be `blend`.